# How do field type can affects the performance of index in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table where the PRIMARY KEY is a field which type is VARCHAR

```
CREATE TABLE table ( name VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY, ....);
```

does the type of the field affect the performance on the indexing over this table? in order words is it good to says that the following table will perform better in indexing tuples ?

```
CREATE TABLE table ( name INT PRIMARY KEY, ....);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Obviously there is more data to index with long strings. That affects the time spent to build the index, time to look up values in the index and also disk and memory usage. This is repeated for any foreign-keys that reference your primary key too.

However. If your "name" needs a unique constraint anyway you'll end up with a unique index on that column regardless. Then you're just down to what foreign keys you might have.

Before you start worrying too much though, spend some time measuring the impact with some realistic data and activity. If it's not worth the time to measure properly then it's probably not worth worrying about either.

Comment: thanks for you answer. anyway if I want to go from VARCHAR to INT in order to gain space and look-up speed, is there technics that you  could recommand for that? I've hear about things like, hash-map but i don't have any reference to start with in postgresql

Comment: @FopaLéonConstantin If you're not comfortable changing a key type, then seriously, you probably have lower hanging peformance fruit. Don't assume this is a problem. Go find and solve real performance problems using profiling and testing, don't just "optimize" what you don't know is a performance issue yet. Get to be friends with `explain analyze`, query plan reading and http://explain.depesz.com/, `auto_explain`, `pg_stat_statements`, etc.